# Issue With mapping 2D to 1D array in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I had written the following code in CUDA

```
__global__ void test(int *b_dev)
{
  int index=blockDim.x*blockIdx.x+threadIdx.x;
  b_dev[index]=1;
 }

 int main()
 {
   int **a;
   int *b_dev;
   a=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*4);
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
     a[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);

   //initialise array a here with 0

   cudaMalloc((void**)&b_dev,sizeof(int)*16);
   cudaMemcpy(b_dev,a,sizeof(int)*16,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   test<<<4,4>>>(dev_b);
   cudaMemcpy(a,b_dev,sizeof(int)*16,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
     for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        cout<<a[i][j];
  }
```

I have this 2d array in host which i flatten as 1D array and process in gpu but this code produces a segmentation fault when i try to print the array a,in the host,but when i comment out the line `b_dev[valindex]=1` in kernal,it prints the array `a` with the initialised zeroes. The visual c++ debugger indicates that

> CXX0030:Error Expression cannot be evaluated.

kindly please lead me on

Comment: You are copying the data incorrectly to and from the gpu. A 2D array allocated in this way cannot be copied directly by using a single memory copy. Also, shouldn't the specified statement be `b_dev[index]=1;` ?

Comment: ya it is b_dev[index]=1.It was a typo..can you please point me to how this can be achieved

Comment: or is there any alternative means?

Comment: if you have a 2D array, you'll need multiple memcpy calls. Do you *need* to use a 2D array, or can you just use 1D arrays everywhere?

Comment: will i be able to run this if i flatten the host 2d array into host 1d array?if so that is sufficient

Comment: still i would  like to know about the multiple memcpy calls

Comment: @Stormvirux I addressed those 2 things in my answer, let me know if you need clarification or elaboration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an array of arrays allocated in the manner that you do, you have no guarentee that each of the arrays will be contiguous in memory. More specifically, in your example you have an `int**` array `a`, which consists of 4 `int*` arrays, `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and `a[3]`. Within each array a[i] (where i is the array index into your 2D array) the memory will be contiguous. However, there's no guarentee that the memory for array `a[i]` and the memory for array `a[i+1]` are. That is, between your calls to `malloc`, the memory being allocated can be from anywhere in your free store, and whether or not they're contiguous is up to `malloc`. (as an aside, if you allocated the memory on the stack, then it would be contiguous, or on the heap as a 1D array).

Thus, you can't expect 1 call to `cudaMemcpy` to copy over all of your arrays. Instead, you'd have to perform multiple `cudaMemcpy` calls for each 1D array in order to copy all of them, and do pointer arithmatic on your destination pointer to ensure that they are copied to the correct location.

When working with contiguous 2D data, you can use `cudaMemcpy2D`, which has the signature:

```
cudaError_t cudaMemcpy2D ( void* dst, size_t dpitch, const void* src, size_t spitch, size_t width, size_t height, cudaMemcpyKind kind )
```

you can use this if you know the source and destination pitch lengths, and take the pitch into account when using the data. However, this function assumes that the data dimensions are contiguous, so it wouldn't help you in your case.

Of course, the easiest solution is to choose an array dimension protocol and stick with it (e.g. either have all your memory be 2D or all 1D, but don't mix them unless you have a compelling reason to).

Also I'd be remiss if I didn't leave a link to the [relevant CUDA documentation about cudaMemcpy](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375)